# SSRS Date column sorting

Tags: sql, sql-server, sorting, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a SSRS 2008 R2 tablix which displays like this :

```
 _____________________________
|               |    Date     |
|_____________________________|
|     Row1      |             |
|     Row2      |             |     
|     Row3      |             |
|_______________|_____________|
```

The Date displays data in `YYYY/mmm` format (`2015/01 , 2015/02, 2015/03`). This column has a grouping on it (column group).

The current sorting sorts the dates incorrectly (`2015/1 , 2015/10 , 2015/11`)

I have tried sorting by adding a sorting option in the Tablix Properties (AtoZ) but this doesn't work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: are your dates stored as strings?

Comment: @JeremyC. Yes, they are...

Comment: I recommend just casting your string as a date for the order by statement, or just not storing dates in a string column but it's too late for that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your dates are probably stored as strings.

So convert them to date

```
CAST(yourDateString AS DATE)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can apply conversion in sorting expression. Try to use:

=CDate(Fields!DateString.Value)

[image]